# Плавающий блок не наползающий на элементы под ним

Tags: javascript, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var box = $('#stickydiv'); // float-fixed block

            var top = box.offset().top - parseFloat(box.css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop()-100;
                if(windowpos < top) {
                    box.css('position', 'static');
                } else {
                    box.css('position', 'fixed');
                    box.css('top', 0);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Сделал плавающий блок, но есть проблема если он доходит на элемент под нужной областью плавания, он заползает на него, как сделать так в этом коде чтобы он останавливался при достижении определенного элемента?